# Why don't health bonus items seem to work?

Tags: kingdoms-of-amalur-reckoning

In Kingdoms of Amalur, Reckoning, I have a level 4 character with 69 max health. When I equip a ring that gives me "+5 Health" the health number doesn't seem to change at all. Is this a bug?

Comment: Are you on the PC? Could you provide some screenshots to show what exactly you're doing?

Comment: More an oversight than a bug.

Answer (score 9):

When you equip an item that gives you additional HP and go back to the menu you won't see any changes to your health. But if you close the menu, go back to the game and then open the menu again you will see you have more HP than you had before equipping the item.

Comment: Manipulating your stats via 3rd party cheating tools also requires you to close and reopen the menu if you want to see the changes. Apparently the main menu display doesn't "listen" for changes, it simply checks your stats upon open.

Answer (score -1):

The same thing happened to me and closing and re-opening the menu didn't change anything. I have +10 on my gloves and sword, so I suspect that health bonuses simply do not stack.

Maybe they want to encourage you to diversify or something, but it also means you must constantly destroy redundant gear.

On second thought... Now suddenly it works. I'm clueless... Maybe certain bonuses stack, others don't. But you must exit then menu first, then do something (roll, strike, whatwver) then enter the menu.

Comment: If you want to change your answer to the question, you can edit it after it is posted.  Please don't post a new answer if you need to update an existing one.